# How to tell docker run to run the latest image from docker hub?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerhub

Im using the following command to run an image off docker hub

```
docker run -it -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=localdocker" -p 8080:8080  name/repo:8 /bin/bash
```

Two questions:

1. First of all, is there a way to not have to keep increment the number next to the repo each time CI uploads a new image? Is there a way to say just run the latest?
2. What is the command to run if I want to stop the current instance and instead restart it with a newer image from the hub?

Comment: There's very little context here. Idiomatically you would push the `latest` tag or a tag of the branch name - e.g. `master`. Usually you would push both a version tag and a `latest` tag and people might want to pin to a version.

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13331

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, if you are using any CI tool then you can dynamically substitute the new created docker image tag to a variable.

Say - dockerimage:${buildID} , you can replace this buildID dynamically via your CI tool

2. While creating container, always give it a name, such that you can execute

   docker stop

command on that container, to stop it and then clear the container permanently too, if you want to reuse that container name always, if you execute

```
docker ps -a | grep give_container_name_here
```

it will give you that container and then you can delete that via

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a | grep give_container_name_here)
```

Then you can restart docker container with new docker image that you have created via CI pipeline